# Crash when signing with RSA/SHA-1

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, keychain

I am using below code for sing string with private key.

I have private key in iPhone keychain. Now get private key in keychain and pass into PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey:

```
- (NSString *)RSASHA1HashForString:(NSString *)source {

    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]
                                         initWithIdentifier:@"TestKeychain"
                                         accessGroup:@"keys"];       

    if (source == nil) return nil;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    NSString *signature = nil;

    // make a SHA-1 digest of the source string
    const char* sourceChars = [source UTF8String];

    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1((const unsigned char *)sourceChars, strlen(sourceChars), digest);        

    FILE *secretFile;
    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    @try {
        NSData *privateKeyFileData = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];

        secretFile = (__bridge FILE *)(privateKeyFileData);

        PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",[exception description]);
    }

    if (rsa != NULL) {

        unsigned int sigLen = 0;
        unsigned char *sigBuff = malloc(RSA_size(rsa));

        int result = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, digest, (unsigned int) sizeof(digest),
                              sigBuff, &sigLen, rsa);

        if (result != 0) {
            NSData *sigData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sigBuff length:sigLen];
            signature = [self base64forData:sigData];                
        }

        free(sigBuff);            
        RSA_free(rsa);
    }

    return signature;
}
```

---

But it getting crash on below code,

```
FILE *secretFile;
RSA *rsa = NULL;
@try {
    NSData *privateKeyFileData = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];

    secretFile = (__bridge FILE *)(privateKeyFileData);

    PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue, I don't have PEM file, I have private key in Keychain.

Comment: you are "getting crash" !? that is interesting to know - far more interesting however would the exact crash reason be! As well as the line number for example...

Comment: I am getting crash on line PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

Comment: *"Is there any way to resolve this issue, I don't have PEM file, I have private key in Keychain."* - that's another question (and its a very good question because the code is non-trivial). It consists of (1) fetch the item from the keychain; (2) retrieve the various parameters from the dictionary and put then in a `RSA`, and then (3) sign.

Comment: I am implementing SSO concept, So My parent application create public key and private key and store in keychain, and keychain are shared, so every SSO enable application access public key and private key, Now I have string kind of token, so token will sign private key, which located in keychain, but above method required .PEM file, but I don't have, What should i do, please guid me here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
> ```

Try:

```
rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(privateKeyFile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

---

```
// make a SHA-1 digest of the source string
const char* sourceChars = [source UTF8String];
```

This is not needed. `RSA_sign` will digest the data for you.

Comment: Hello, Still crash on this line rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(privateKeyFile, NULL, NULL, NULL);